# If i replace false and !== with true and === the function gives unexpected results. Any explanation?

Tags: javascript, palindrome

```
function palindrome(str) {
    var len = str.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < Math.floor(len/2); i++ ) {
       if (str[i] !== str[len - 1 - i]) {
          return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
   }
```

If I replace !== and false inside the for loop with === and true and outside true with false the function does not work as expected Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Write out your algorithm for determining a palindrome. Think about what the intent of having an exit clause inside the for lop is (and indeed inside of the function as a whole). Do you want to stop checking for matches when two letters match or when two letters don't match?

Comment: PS. A return statement returns from the function, not from the if block. So using `===` and *true* you loop for the false results and return true at the first match. Using `!==` and *false* you loop for the matches and return false for the first non–match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me illustrate it on an example

Let's say we have covered box full of white and black marbles. And a statement: "The box contains only white marbles". How can you be sure, that the statement is true? Well... you pick marbles one by one (in a for loop) and check if they are all white. If you'll find one that **is not (!==)**, you know that the statement **is false**. And your function is doing this.

The way you want it - with switched operator and true value - it'll go like this: "I will pick one marble and if it **IS** white **(===)**, I know the statement is **true**." Now... is it really true? No it isn't.

Got it? (In your case you are not checking the black and white marbles but whether the characters are equal or not)